# How to run a for loop in nextflow

Tags: for-loop, nextflow

Here's the problem I'm having with the run for loop in nextflow, my script doesn't seem to be working. Here is my pairs file, with 3 pairs in total and I want to have each of the three pairs executed once in a process.These pair files are stored in "/data/mPCR/3samples_20220525/" path.

```
V350092589_L01_86_1.fq.gz  
V350092589_L01_86_2.fq.gz

V350092589_L01_85_1.fq.gz          
V350092589_L01_85_2.fq.gz

V350092589_L01_84_1.fq.gz            
V350092589_L01_84_2.fq.gz
```

Here is my script

```
params.fq = "/data/mPCR/3samples_20220525/" 
   
process soapnuke{
        tag{"soapnuk"}
    
        input:
            val fq from params.fq
    
        output:
            path '*.clean1.fastq.gz' into trim_primer1
            path '*.clean2.fastq.gz' into trim_primer2
    
    script:
        """
        sample1=\$(basename \$(readlink 1.fq.gz) _1.fq.gz)
        sample2=\$(basename \$(readlink 2.fq.gz) _2.fq.gz)
    
        SOAPnuke filter -1 \$fq*1.fq.gz -2 \$fq*2.fq.gz -o ./ -C \${sample1}.clean.fastq.gz -D \${sample2}.clean.fastq.gz
        """
    }
```

What should I do to run all the pairs in this process? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need a  `for` loop. Just read in the files using the [`fromFilePairs`](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/channel.html#fromfilepairs) factory method. It'll give you a [queue channel](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/channel.html#queue-channel) that you can use to feed your 'soapnuke' process. Just make sure the input tuples match the input set cardinality declared by the process. Here's one way using [DSL 2](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/dsl2.html) syntax:

```
params.reads = "/data/mPCR/3samples_20220525/*_{1,2}.fq.gz"

process soapnuke {

    tag { sample }
    cpus 6

    input:
    tuple val(sample), path(reads)

    output:
    tuple val(sample), path("${sample}_{1,2}.clean.fq.gz")

    script:
    def (fq1, fq2) = reads

    """
    SOAPnuke filter \\
        -T ${task.cpus} \\
        -1 "${fq1}" \\
        -2 "${fq2}" \\
        -C "${sample}_1.clean.fq.gz" \\
        -D "${sample}_2.clean.fq.gz" \\
        -o ./
    """
}

workflow {

    sample_reads = Channel.fromFilePairs( params.reads )

    soapnuke( sample_reads ).view()
}
```

Results:

```
$ nextflow run script.nf
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 22.04.3
Launching `script.nf` [ecstatic_waddington] DSL2 - revision: 09ce9cdd71
executor >  local (3)
[25/7cd2d1] process > soapnuke (V350092589_L01_86) [100%] 3 of 3 ✔
[V350092589_L01_85, [/path/to/work/6e/46ce05bc757b4e706e6c450b3ad875/V350092589_L01_85_1.clean.fq.gz, /path/to/work/6e/46ce05bc757b4e706e6c450b3ad875/V350092589_L01_85_2.clean.fq.gz]]
[V350092589_L01_84, [/path/to/work/20/ada65f53d299a9d34fb02920e1c394/V350092589_L01_84_1.clean.fq.gz, /path/to/work/20/ada65f53d299a9d34fb02920e1c394/V350092589_L01_84_2.clean.fq.gz]]
[V350092589_L01_86, [/path/to/work/25/7cd2d150b8edef9713bfb226404b0f/V350092589_L01_86_1.clean.fq.gz, /path/to/work/25/7cd2d150b8edef9713bfb226404b0f/V350092589_L01_86_2.clean.fq.gz]]
```

Comment: Thank you @Steve, your script worked perfectly! Could you write this process in a dsl1-based script ? Actually, I'm not familiar with dsl2 and my entire script is based on dsl1.  Thank you again!

Comment: No worries @Daffy. You could absolutely rewrite this using the original DSL. Simply remove the `workflow` block and move the input channel declaration (i.e. `sample_reads = ...`) up top (i.e. before the 'soapnuke' process declaration). Finally, change the 'soapnuke' input declaration to: `tuple val(sample), path(reads) from sample_reads` and you should be good.

Comment: Thank you again @Steve! I followed your suggestion to modify my script and it worked perfectly! As a budding bioinformatician, it's very pinchy at times, thank you for your help.

Comment: No worries at all, @Daffy! If it answered your question, please considering marking it as accepted. You may also like to review some of your previous questions/answers, see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers thanks!

Comment: Just a reminder @Daffy please consider marking the post "accepted". Its a nice bit of `NextFlow` code with the important `Channel.fromFilePairs` command. No relation to the person answering, but its useful code.